# Application doesn't authenticate in canvas

Tags: facebook, sinatra

My facebook application redirects the user a page where they give the application window correctly when they visit the website (http://toolshed.herokuapp.com/), but not when they visit the canvas page in Facebook (https://apps.facebook.com/toolshed/).  Once a user has given permission to the application, both places work correctly.  The main problem here is that when a user goes to the page on Facebook first, all they see is a blank page.  Any ideas?  The code can be found at https://github.com/runninggraeb/toolshed, but I doubt it's a coding issue.  Any help would be appreciated.

Ryan

Answer: To clarify to future viewers, I did redirected to this page within the app for authentication.  "top.window.location" gets me out of the iFrame.

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#" lang="en">
  <script>
    window.top.location = '<%= authenticator.url_for_oauth_code %>'
  </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not display the Auth dialog in any kind of frame. (As has been said here already many times before …)

You have to redirect to it in the top most window instance.